# Windows cli elusive escape

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch, escape-characters

After reading [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317491/proxycommand-use-for-multiple-hops-and-prompt-authentication) I found that while I know how to escape in linux/bash I did not fair so well in windows cmd/batch. Anyone know how to properly escape the windows version of the command below? Please forgive the full path it is [because of a bug](https://serverfault.com/questions/956613/windows-10-ssh-proxycommand-posix-spawn-no-such-file-or-directory).

Linux (works!)

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -W %h:%p user@jmp1\" user@jmp2" user@dest
```

Windows (tried multiple % characters to no avail!)

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -W %h:%p -o ProxyCommand=\"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -W %h:%p user@jmp1\" user@jmp2" user@dest
Bad stdio forwarding specification '%h:%p'
```

Yes I know about the ssh '-J' parameter and yes I can already achieve the same result by using ssh configs, but at this point I am really trying to learn about windows command escapes.

**UPDATE 1**
Remove unnecessary double percent

Comment: the standard escape character is `^`, though there are nuances like quotes (which you generally double), etc. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Ok yes looks like the double percent is unnecessary. However the command still fails in windows with `Bad stdio forwarding specification '%h:%p'`any ideas?

Comment: Look at answers and comments here for some clues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53082071/bad-stdio-forwarding-specification-hp ... Don't forget to try `^%h:^%p` in all areas too as indicated by another comment

Answer (score 0):

Try using double-double-quotes inside to escape them. I also did need to use double percent symbols, or else ssh would expand the wrong pair. (don't include these line breaks):

```
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -o 
  ProxyCommand="C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -W %h:%p -o 
    ProxyCommand=""C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -W %%h:%%p"" user@jmp1"" 
  user@jmp2" 
user@dest
```

I think this has more to do with how ssh.exe is parsing the `ProxyCommands` parameter instead of how to escape stuff in CMD itself (along the same lines as the bug requiring full paths).

I only had one jump to test with though, so it might be missing a part